# Using chrome.runtime.reload make the extention crx deactivate/disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want make a reload to my extention after click event on a button in the popup.js

```
$("#saveChange").click(function(){
     var urlToBlock = $('#urlToBlock').val();
     var urlsToBlockArr = urlToBlock.split(",");
     console.log(urlsToBlockArr.length);
     chrome.storage.sync.set({ "urlToBlock": urlsToBlockArr });
     chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){  
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{type: 'reload'});    
     });
     setTimeout(function(){
         debugger;
         chrome.runtime.reload(); // reload the chrome extention, must for the url blocking
     },2); 
});
```

This is working while i'm loading an unpack extention, but if i pack it and load the crx file, the extention is getting disabled after the reload was made.

There is any way to prevent my extention from getting disabled? there is any other way to reload the extention?

Comment: While this would be an interesting question in and of itself (if it had a [mcve]), your actual issue looks like an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). I'm having a hard time thinking of a situation, where you are doing what you state, where it is better to reload the extension rather than write your code such that reloading the extension is not needed. I suggest you [create another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which is about solving the underlying issue(s) which you believe require you to reload the extension.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.